# WebView scroll position?

Tags: android, android-intent, scroll, webview, position

I have this code ::

```
    //Scroll position from last time
    String scrollPos = intent.getExtras().getString("SCROLL");
    //chapter position from last time (this is a book app)
    String chapterPos = intent.getExtras().getString("EXTRA");
    //this methode changes the webView content according to last chapter visited (it works fine)
    doItNow(chapterPos);

    // PROBLEM IS HERE !!!!
    if(scrollPos!=null) {

        float webviewsize = webView.getContentHeight() - webView.getTop();
        float positionInWV = webviewsize * (Float.parseFloat(scrollPos));
        int positionY = Math.round(webView.getTop() + positionInWV);
        webView.scrollTo(0, positionY);
    }
```

I want my webView to be scrolled automatically to the last scrolling position ?? but it does not work ??

**EDIT**
this is my full Activity for now :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
public class book extends AppCompatActivity {

private String extra;
private WebView webView;
private TextView textView;
private Intent intent;
private LinearLayout Linear1;
private RelativeLayout Relative1;
private int colorId;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private View layout;
private TextView text;
private Toast toast;
public int flag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    webView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    Linear1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.Linear1);
    Relative1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Relative1);

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/arabicfont.otf");
    textView.setTypeface(face);

    intent = getIntent();
    colorId = intent.getIntExtra("COLOR_EXTRA", colorId);

    Linear1.setBackgroundResource(colorId);
    Relative1.setBackgroundResource(colorId);

    String chapterPos = intent.getExtras().getString("EXTRA");

    doItNow(chapterPos);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                                     @Override
                                     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                                         super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                                         String scrollPos = intent.getExtras().getString("SCROLL");
                                         Toast.makeText(book.this, scrollPos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                         float webviewsize = webView.getContentHeight() - webView.getTop();
                                         float positionInWV = webviewsize * (Float.parseFloat(scrollPos));
                                         int positionY = Math.round(webView.getTop() + positionInWV);
                                         webView.scrollTo(0, positionY);
                                     }

                                 }
    );

}

public void sectionsFnc(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(book.this, storyZero.class);
    intent.putExtra("COLOR_EXTRA", colorId);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void backFunc(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(book.this, FirstScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void nextStory(View view) {

    int iExtra = Integer.parseInt(extra) + 1;

    if(iExtra<=10) {
        extra = String.valueOf(iExtra);
        doItNow(extra);
    } else {
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_root));

        text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("لقد وصلت لنهاية الكتاب!");

        toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }
}

public void preStory(View view) {
    int iExtra = Integer.parseInt(extra) - 1;
    if(iExtra>=0) {
        extra = String.valueOf(iExtra);
        doItNow(extra);
    } else {
        inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_root));

        text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("أنت في بداية الكتاب!");

        toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setView(layout);
        toast.show();
    }
}

private float calculateProgression(WebView content) {
    float positionTopView = content.getTop();
    float contentHeight = content.getContentHeight();
    float currentScrollPosition = content.getScrollY();
    float percentWebview = (currentScrollPosition - positionTopView) / contentHeight;
    return percentWebview;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    float position = calculateProgression(webView);
    SharedPreferences sharePref = getSharedPreferences("webviewScroll", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharePref.edit();
    editor.putFloat("SCROLLPOS", position);
    editor.putInt("CHAPTER", flag);
    editor.commit();
    super.onStop();
}

public void doItNow(String mExtra) {

    extra = mExtra;

    if(extra.equals("0")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/1.htm");
        flag = 0;

    } else if(extra.equals("1")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/2.htm");
        flag = 1;

    } else if(extra.equals("2")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/3.htm");
        flag = 2;

    } else if(extra.equals("3")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/4.htm");
        flag = 3;
    } else if(extra.equals("4")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/5.htm");
        flag = 4;

    } else if(extra.equals("5")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/6.htm");
        flag = 5;

    } else if(extra.equals("6")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/7.htm");
        flag = 6;

    } else if(extra.equals("7")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/8.htm");
        flag = 7;

    } else if(extra.equals("8")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/9.htm");
        flag = 8;

    } else if(extra.equals("9")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/10.htm");
        flag = 9;

    } else if(extra.equals("10")) {
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/11.htm");
        flag = 10;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: does scrollPos return null?

Comment: no, it returns a float value but it doesnt scroll

Answer (score 0):

please paste your full code to identify the problem but i'm guessing that you are calling the scrollTo before the webview finished loading the page so in this case you have to use

```
yourWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            yourWebView.scrollTo(xVal, yVal);
        }

    }
    );
```

and if your page contains images you can use this

```
yourWebView.setPictureListener(new PictureListener() {

        @Override
        public void onNewPicture(WebView view, Picture picture) {
             yourWebView.scrollTo(xVal, yVal);

        }
    });
```

Comment: how to do this >> I edited my post with the full activity